# How can I upload multiple files one at a time?

Tags: html, forms, post, get, request

I am using the input type='file' multiple  element, but do to server side restrictions I can only upload one document at a time.  So I am struggling to find a way to do this, while keeping just the single file input element... I think my only options are to create multiple forms with their own hidden file input elements and as I loop through the files somehow set the value of the hidden input field, but I'm not sure how.  Any reccomendations? Here is what I have so far:

```
HTML:
<form method='POST' id='frmUploadDoc' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='hiddenIframe' action='/wle/rest'>
    <input type="file" name="data" multiple="multiple" id="filesInput">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<iframe name="hiddenIframe" id="hiddenIframe" style="display: none;">

JAVASCRIPT:
function handleFileSelect(evt) {      
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList is a FileList of File objects.  
    var output = [];
    var actionText;
    for (var iCount = 0, f; f = files[iCount]; iCount++) {
       actionText="/wle/rest?action=addDocument&name=" + iCount   //This creates the unique action URL for each individual form  
       $("#frmUploadDoc").attr("action", actionText);
       output.push("<li><strong>", f.name, "</strong></li>");
       postDocumentToWLE(iCount);            
    }
    document.getElementById('listDocs').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }
```

Comment: `"but do to server side restrictions I can only upload one document at a time"` - Depending on what those restrictions are and how they're implemented, there may not be much that client-side code can do for you.  Are you trying to upload multiple files in a single POST, or asynchronously upload them with multiple POSTs via AJAX?

Comment: The application has a REST API, so we can use a POST request using the hidden iframe method as documented http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/iframe-post-form.html.  As of now I have it set to submit one form but I wonder if there is a way to simply parse the selected files from the input and for each file just create a new form with its own file input.  For that to work I would need to be able to assign a file to that new file element though and I don't know how I could do that.

Comment: If I could even just resubmit the same for over and over again and each time just take out the other files... this would work too.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, it does appear David is correct that with form uploads via a POST through an iframe it is not possible to upload multiple files.  HTML5 allows for the multiple file upload but if you need to send each file individually this is not possible using a multiple file input.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but depending on what requirements you have on browser support you should be able to do it using FormData.

You can access all files selected in an input field with the multiple attribute by reading the  files property:

```
var files = document.getElementById('input').files;
```

Then you can loop through the files, create a FormData object for each one and fire away an AJAX request, one at the time.
For a more detailed explanation with code examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Remember though, that not all browsers support the FormData object. But then again, all browsers don't support the multiple attribute either...